# Will installing Visual Studio 2013 Preview mess up 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I’m currently developing with Visual Studio 2012, and I was wondering – would my environment be messed up by installing the Visual Studio 2013 Preview?

Comment: When in doubt use a VM to play around. (I think they can coexist side-by-side, or at least 2012 and 2010 could, but you're really just asking for trouble considering how ludicrously complex a piece of software VS is.)

Comment: If nothing else, set a system restore point and try it out?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no such a way it could mess up your projects or whatever. It is like using 2010 and 2012. Your question is too complex, but generally Microsoft will také care of this problem at all. I can say that I have installed 2013 Preview and I could work with both and nothing bad happened to me.

Comment: Well, it works fine, except that every time you open it (at least for me) it complains about a .vssettings file. Also when I close it

Comment: I haven't had much conflict between the two yet, but due to Visual Studio 2013 adding a Hyper-V Role on the system, VMware Workstation 9 is no longer working. It says I must Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [known issues for Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2848395) imply that installing it is **safe**. One of the issues is [“The remaining Visual Studio application is broken after you uninstall Visual Studio 2013 Preview or Visual Studio 2012”](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2858349):

> ### Symptoms
>
> Consider the following scenario:
>
> [basically, you have installed VS 2013 Preview]
>
> In this scenario, when you uninstall Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 Preview, the application that was not uninstalled is broken.
>
> ### Workaround
>
> To work around this issue, repair the Visual Studio application that remains on your computer.

It says that an application is broken when you uninstall the other one. That implies that before that, when they were both installed, they were unbroken and working fine.

That issue itself is nothing to worry about, as long as you remember to repair your remaining Visual Studio application after uninstalling another.